# System.Exception when I try to send email

Tags: c#, email, exception, smtp

I am trying to send an email with c#. Everything seems to be ok no errors but when  the programms tries to send the mail I get an exception : "System.Exception - Exception was not treated"

here is the code:

```
public void sendMail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 100;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymailaddress@googlemail.com", "mypassword");

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("mymailaddress@googlemail.com", "receiveremailaddress", "test", "test");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;


         client.Send(mm); // HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION !!!!!





    }
```

Comment: Bad practice.  Any code above that `throw` will have no knowledge of what actually happened.  If you don't mean to deal with the exception properly, then don't catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your timeout is far too short try:

```
client.Timeout = 5000;
```

[The default value is 100,000 (100 seconds)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx), but smtp.gmail.com is fast enough that if you want to use 5000 it should be fine.

Also as per the above comment to your post; handle your exception (this is a very basic way of doing so).

```
try
{
...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Console.Writeline(ex);
}
```

Comment: :) thank you! yes the timeout was to short ! I changed it to 5000 and now everything wokrs perfectly

Comment: @haddow64, your comment about handling the exception by printing it to the console is bad advice.  You should always let the exception bubble up unless you intend to *actually* handle the error or log it in a top-level exception handler.